# Rejected promise still call to the next .then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

Here is a promise chain that rejects 100%. I expect the first `console.log` to print, but after that because of the rejected promise it should skips to `.catch` at the end

```
function stringProcessor(string)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(`Calling ${string}`)
        reject(`Rejected ${string}`)
    });
}

exports.concat = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    return stringProcessor("foo")
    .then(stringProcessor("bar"))
    .then(stringProcessor("hello"))
    .then(response.send("no problem!"))
    .catch(e => 
    { 
        console.log("CAUGHT : " + e)
        response.send("not ok")
    })
})
```

However the output log is

```
info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: Calling foo
info: Calling bar
info: Calling hello
info: CAUGHT : Rejected foo
info: Execution took 15 ms, user function completed successfully
error: (node:67568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Rejected bar
error: (node:67568) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:67568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Rejected hello
```

Not only that everything has been called sequentially, also I have been warned about uncaught promise even if the CAUGHT line clearly prints.

Comment: i mean, calling foo bar and hello is expected. you called them to return the promise afterall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass function which returns promise in `then`:

```
return stringProcessor("foo")
.then(() => stringProcessor("bar"))
.then(() => stringProcessor("hello"))
// ...
```

In your example you are not passing functions, but promises.

Comment: I see! I have went to MDN and read carefully again. Now the erroneous log make sense because 1. [The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and 2. [`.then` resolves to its original settled value if the promise was not handled (i.e. if the relevant handler onFulfilled or onRejected is not a function).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/prototype)